# Feeding in data from a file to save to a file

Tags: terminal, macos

Write a command that

- feeds app data from `input.dat`
- saves the output to `output.dat`
- saves the error messages to `log.txt`

I am really new to Unix and was wondering if I am using the command line parameters correctly.

My command I was writing was:

`$> app < input.dat > output.dat > 2> log.txt`

From what I understand is the `<` reads files as standard input. `>` sets files as redirection from standard output, and `2>` redirects error messages to a file.

Was wondering if my command is correct, and if not was wondering if someone could lend me a hand in this.

Comment: You just have an extra output redirection `>` in there. So `app < input.dat > output.dat 2> log.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the app handles its input and assuming the input data is formatted correctly you could do something like this `cat input.dat | app > output.dat 2> log.txt`.  The input is the part that hold most of the issues this really depends on how the app expects to receive its input ie. newline separated, tab separated ect..

You can also use the syntax you originally where trying.

`app < input.dat > output.dat 2> log.txt`

But personally I think the `cat` method is more versatile and common usage in Linux.